# Bokeh hover tooltip to show data from a different column

Tags: python, plot, bokeh

I have the code below. I want the hover tooltip for the bars to show which account they are from. It is unclear to me how the `hover.tooltips` parameter should be used to retrieve data from the `account` column in the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_notebook, show
output_notebook()

sales = [{'account': 'Jones LLC', 'sales': 150, 'day' : 1},
         {'account': 'Alpha Co',  'sales': 200, 'day' : 2},
         {'account': 'Blue Inc',  'sales': 50, 'day' : 3}]
df = pd.DataFrame(sales)

TOOLS = "hover,save,pan,box_zoom,reset,wheel_zoom"
p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, y_axis_label="sales", tools=TOOLS)
p.vbar(x=df.day, bottom=0, top=df.sales, width=0.25)

hover = p.select(dict(type=HoverTool))
hover.tooltips = [("account", "@account")]

show℗
```

---

**A second reproducible example where tooltips are not showing**

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_notebook, show
from bokeh.models import HoverTool
output_notebook()

data = {'rt_by': ['somename', 'somename', 'somename', 'somename', 'somename', 'somename', 'somename', 'somename', 'somename', 'somename', 'somename', 'somename', 'somename', 'somename', 'somename', 'somename', 'somename', 'somename', 'somename', 'somename', 'somename', 'somename', 'somename', 'somename', 'somename', 'somename', 'somename', 'somename', 'somename', 'somename', 'somename', 'somename', 'somename', 'somename', 'somename', 'somename', 'somename'], 'to_followers': [473, 301, 172, 149, 2422, 106, 16, 3173, 562, 354, 1154, 301, 1228, 261, 204, 471, 2422, 22, 222, 965, 965, 869, 473, 63452, 3095, 220, 2177, 22, 69, 128, 2422, 1277, 702, 959, 365, 398, 3928], 'date': ['2018-01-25 16:39:03','2018-01-25 16:51:06','2018-01-25 17:05:31','2018-01-25 17:11:30','2018-01-25 21:31:26','2018-01-25 21:56:12','2018-01-25 23:15:17','2018-01-28 07:14:48','2018-01-28 07:43:35','2018-01-28 12:22:26','2018-01-28 20:15:29','2018-01-28 20:42:11','2018-01-29 07:35:38','2018-01-29 08:28:07','2018-01-29 09:32:24','2018-01-29 13:45:28','2018-01-29 14:53:12','2018-01-30 07:18:18','2018-01-30 07:19:13','2018-01-30 08:55:06','2018-01-30 09:10:30','2018-01-30 09:48:13','2018-01-30 09:49:13','2018-01-30 10:02:40','2018-01-30 10:06:55','2018-01-30 10:15:16','2018-01-30 10:40:50','2018-01-30 10:42:27','2018-01-30 10:46:07','2018-01-30 11:13:12','2018-01-30 11:13:34','2018-01-30 11:54:37','2018-01-30 12:17:02','2018-01-30 12:18:00','2018-01-30 12:26:04','2018-01-30 14:25:18','2018-01-30 14:32:12']}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])


TOOLS = "hover,save,pan,box_zoom,reset,wheel_zoom"

p = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=400, tools=TOOLS)

p.vbar(x='date', bottom=0, top='to_followers', width=1, source=df)

hover = p.select(type=HoverTool)
hover.tooltips = [("rt_by", "@rt_by")]

show(p)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass data directly to glyph methods `vbar`, etc., then Bokeh only sends exactly what you provide and nothing more. If you want to send extra data columns (e.g. to have displayed in a hover tool) then you have to arrange for that by specifying a `source` argument for the glyph, and referring to the column names. Previously this meant creating a `ColumnDataSource` from the dataframe yourself, but with recent versions of Bokeh you can just pass the dataframe directly. See the User Guide chapter [Providing Data](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/data.html) for full details. A complete example is below:

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.models import HoverTool
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

output_file("foo.html")

sales = [{'account': 'Jones LLC', 'sales': 150, 'day' : 1},
         {'account': 'Alpha Co',  'sales': 200, 'day' : 2},
         {'account': 'Blue Inc',  'sales': 50, 'day' : 3}]
df = pd.DataFrame(sales)

TOOLS = "hover,save,pan,box_zoom,reset,wheel_zoom"
p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, y_axis_label="sales", tools=TOOLS)

# THIS LINE CHANGED
p.vbar(x='day', bottom=0, top='sales', width=0.25, source=df)

hover = p.select(dict(type=HoverTool))
hover.tooltips = [("account", "@account")]

show(p)
```

[image]

Comment: It seems the tooltip for the histogram bars is not showing when there are too many (thin) bars. Any ideas?

Comment: It's hard to speculate without a real, complete example to run.

Comment: I edited the initial post with a reproducible example where tooltips are not showing for the bars.

Comment: You need to make the bars thicker. When using datetimes, the axis is denominated in units of milliseconds (since epoch). So currently you are making bars that are 1ms wide. This actually results in zero-pixel-width bar interiors, and what you are really seeing is just the "outline", which will always draw at least one pixel wide. In any case hit testing occurs in data space, so the bars are just way too narrow. Just from some experimentation, `width=1000000` seems to work OK, but obviously you will want to adjust the width of the bars based on their actual spacing.